# Stephen Wolfram claims to deduce the field equations from cellular automata, has anyone seen the actual mathematics?

Tags: general-relativity, cellular-automaton

In his new blog post Stephen Wolfram [claims](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2015/12/what-is-spacetime-really/) that he can derive general relativity from cellular automata.

> OK, so one can derive Special Relativity from simple models based on networks. What about General Relativity—which, after all, is what we’re celebrating today? Here the news is very good too: subject to various assumptions, I managed in the late 1990s to derive Einstein’s Equations from the dynamics of networks.

He links to a a [chapter](http://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/section-9.15) of his book, "A New Kind of Science", a non-mathematical, non-technical book.

There is no mathematics in the linked material, so it's impossible to see whether he is correct, in fact it's impossible to see what he means at all!

So, has anybody seen this **mathematical** derivation of the field equations, and if so, is anyone kind enough to provide this material?

Thanks.

Comment: Meh. I soured on Wolfram's claims long ago when I read his book. Lot's of claims on how cellular automata could be applied to the study of all sorts of things, but no concrete examples. Just a lot of pictures and illustrations noting how his cellular automata patterns looked similar to seashell patterns and other patterns found in nature.

Comment: The general consensus I recall from the release of the book was a big shrug from the physics community. Using cellular automata to _replicate_ things that look like complex physics is very different from using them to actually _predict_ anything useful. And, no, nobody every really saw anything useful - there are no peer-reviewed descriptions out there.

Comment: I agree with comments about Wolfram's book "A New Kind of Science" in general that what he has done seems to be well thought out mostly in his head without too many followers repeating his work.  But, I wonder if he has something of truth in his "network" idea as the foundation of space-time.  This is not much different than other ideas on the fabric of space time (Wheeler's sea foam for example).  Does anyone know of other similar work like Wolfram's network ideas?

Comment: How about loop quantum gravity?  I'm no expert but they sound similar.

Comment: I too wish to see the derivation of Einstein's field equations from networks. But the best that I could find in the works of Stephen Wolfram was https://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-535 where he uses plenty of words like "I suspect" and "Probably'. Another https://www.wolframscience.com/nksonline/page-1052 is maybe a little better, but still no derivation present.

Comment: What about now...? he just published hundreds of pages further iterating on this and a very long blog post.